# Which java.lang.Error descendant are safe to catch?

Tags: java, error-handling, uncaught-exception, throwable, uncaughtexceptionhandler

Its absolutely clear for me, that usually a Java program should not catch `Throwable`, since it is catching `Error`-s like `OutOfMemoryError`. 100% clear.

But.

If I have a multi-threaded application, it is usually a best practice, that I should have an `UncaughtExceptionHandler`, which does something if `RuntimeException` or `Error` happens. What I usually want to do, is simply logging. Logging `RuntimeExceptions` cannot really hurt, thats clear. But the question arises in me:

**Which errors can I catch and log safely in an UncaughtExceptionHandler, which will not treat my whole application if I log it? Which errors are there, which does not mean, that the application must stop immediately?**

For example if I get an `OutOfMemoryError`, I would just ask for a `printStackTrace` to standard out, since the memory need of logging it can kill other threads. But a **`StackOverflowError` seems to me totally safe to be logged**, since it means simply, that the stack area of the current thread became full. It is safe to log it. **Which other `Error` descendants would you log?**

Answer (score 1):

Any Throwable is safe to catch if you can do something constructive with it.  Any Throwable where you can't do something useful, should not be caught.

BTW: For catch all logging, I `catch(Throwable)` for logging purpose when I know the remaining code would otherwise discard the Throwable/Error/Exception.

Comment: I dont understand the "when I know it would otherwise discard it." part. What do you mean by "it"?

Comment: @GáborLipták By "it" I mean the Throwable like an Error or Exception.

Comment: hehe. I have just realized, that this part contains "it" twice. So I meant the first "it". What does it mean?

Comment: @GáborLipták I have replaced the "it" ;)